# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-module

./gradlew clean assembleDebug

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':demoApp:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':demoApp:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :mepAnalytics.
     Required by:
         project :demoApp > project :VisaInAppCore
      > No matching configuration of project :mepAnalytics was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr' with value 'Aar', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

But I have already configure the project module in `settings.gradle`

```
include ':mepAnalytics'
project(':mepAnalytics').projectDir = new File('../mep_analytics_sdk_android/mepAnalytics')
```

Anyone knows why?